# Unstable Mouse Pointer using Synaptics Touchpad

Tags: mouse, touchpad, vaio, sony, synaptics

I have a Sony VAIO SVE1711W1E laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64. The mouse pointer when I'm using the Synaptics touchpad is really inaccurate, when tapping the touchpad the pointer jumps to another location, so the touchpad is practically useless.

I installed the latest gsynaptics pointing driver and tried to fix the problem by changing the min/max speed and acceleration, but the problem still exists.

Thanks in advance!